# React - user login and token validation

Tags: reactjs, axios, es6-promise

I've an AuthService component like this

```
class AuthService {

  // ... some code here

  private static isTokenValid = async (token: string | null) => {

    return await axios.post('https://example.net/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token/validate', null, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }).then(res => {
      if (res.data.status === 200) return true;
    }).catch(e => {
      if (e.response.status === 403) return false;
    });
  }

  public static async isAuthorized() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    let isValid;
    if (token) isValid = await this.isTokenValid(token);

    return token && isValid ? true : false;
  }
}
```

When I try to use it in React component, I got in `isAuthorized` Promise instead of boolean (true/false)

```
import AuthService from '../../services/auth/AuthService';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const NavBar = () => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isAuthorized = AuthService.isAuthorized();
    if (isAuthorized) setIsLoggedIn(isAuthorized);
  }, []);

  return (
     //...something...
  )
}
```

So what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` function always returns a `promise`. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Try with this `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    AuthService
        .isAuthorized()
        .then((isAuthorized) => setIsLoggedIn(isAuthorized))
        .catch(() => setIsLoggedIn(false));
}, []);
```